# Flutter can't build on ios module 'cloud_firestore' not found @import cloud_firestore;

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm using codemagic to deploy to my app on App Store. Android build is fine, but when it builds for IOS I get this error:

```
 /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error: module 'cloud_firestore' not found
    @import cloud_firestore;
```

This is my Podfile.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ’10.0’

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
 # Pods for Runner
end
```

I did pod install and update, but I can't `flutter build ios` because I'm on Windows. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you done all the configuration needed to use firebase on ios, I mean the info.plist and etc? 
Since I know to link the Firestore configuration plist file needs to be linked using Xcode.

Comment: @Hooshyar yes, it works on Android. The only problem is IOS

Comment: You need to add an app on firebase for iOS as well and add the ios config file to the `.xcworkspace` file.

Comment: @Hooshyar thank you. I added to Googleinfoplist to ```Runner```. I also added the necessary lines to ```project.pbxproj ```. What do you mean ios config file?

Comment: I meant this Googleinfoplist

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem multiple times, here is my process for fixing it:

- upgrade Firebase pub package
- Remember to have the Firebase Core package added as well
- Remember to add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` to the Runner folder of your `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` using `Xcode` since it needs to be linked.
- using terminal `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`
- `cd ios`
- `pod cache clean --all`
- `pod install`
- `pod update`

then try to run the project again or build it again.

Answer (score -1):

For me I just update deployment target to the same as define in Pod file.

Note you need to open `Runner.xcworkspace` not `Runner.xcodeproj`

Comment: I mentioned in the questions that I use windows.